# Add data to array within array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So heres my mongodb document:

```
{
"_id" : "",
"lists" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "list 1",
        "items" : []
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "list 2",
        "items" : []
    }
]
}
```

How would I go about adding an object inside "items"?

This is the code I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
xxx.update(_id, {$push: { "lists.$.items": item}});
```

Note that I have access to the index (variable called 'index'), so its possible to insert an item at index, 0, 1, 2..., etc.

I tried this before, but it won't work:

```
xxx.update({_id, "lists": index}, {$push: { "lists.$.items": item}});
```

I also looked at other similar questions and couldn't find anything. Most of them have some sort of id field in their arrays, but I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
xxx.update({_id}, {$push: { "lists.index.items": item}});
```

Of course this would fail, what I mean is replace index with real index values

```
xxx.update({_id}, {$push: { "lists.2.items": item}});
```

You can manipulate the update json based on the index maybe as below.

```
var update = '{$push: { "lists.'+index+'.items": '+item+'}}';
var updateObj = JSON.parse(update);
xxx.update({_id}, updateObj);
```

Not sure if it will work as it is or it would need further tweaking, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sorry, I can't just enter the number directly, I need to use the variable so its reusable. Is there a way?

Comment: I understand you cannot hard code it, what I meant is you prepare a string based on your variable and parse it as a json through JSON.parse and then use that object.

Comment: Is there a way to do that in javascript? I also did a bit of searching and I'm starting to think this is impossible, because of mongoDBs current limitations

Comment: Updated the answer and yeah it's not good design to put array of object inside array, Queries and indexes won't be efficient specially if you deal with inner nested array.